# What is the difference between writing `:name => "String"` and `name: "String"`?

Tags: ruby, hashrocket

Is there a difference between writing

```
parameter: "String"
```

and the lengthier

```
:parameter => "String"
```

Comment: No difference. Apart from personal preferences.

Comment: @Sergio: What happens if you `'ha ha': 6` or `$set: { p: 11 }`?

Comment: @muistooshort: well, he asked about symbols. With symbols - no difference :)

Comment: @Sergio: `:'ha ha'` and `:$set` are both symbols and things like `:$set` are quite common when working with MongoDB...

Comment: @muistooshort: I know. I should have given more general answer. That's why I left a comment (which I should probably delete now).

Answer (score 4):

The first one does not work in Ruby 1.8

Answer (score 2):

They both construct a hash key-value pair.  For the most part they are interchangeable.  The `parameter: "String"` syntax was introduced in Ruby 1.9 and is modeled after [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

There are some differences/gotchas.  The biggest one is that the newer syntax doesn't handle quoted keys.  In a 1.8-style hash, you can do this:

```
:"multi word key" => some_value
```

In a 1.9-style hash, this is a syntax error:

```
"multi word key": some_value
```

Answer (score 0):

No difference.

I prefer 2nd syntax as I think it's easier to see when doing brief overview.

In Ruby 1.9.x and 2.0.0

Comment: Incorrect, some symbols are only valid with the hashrocket syntax. You also **must** use the hashrocket if your Hash has non-symbol keys.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a syntactic Sugar.

If you see in irb with Ruby 1.8.7

```
1.8.7 :004 > {:name => 'String'}
 => {:name=>"String"}
```

and With 1.9.3

```
1.9.3p392 :002 > {name: 'String'}
 => {:name=>"String"}
```

Both return the same format.